# Java / box2DLights - Wrong light position

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, light, box2dlights

I'm using Libgdx for a project and more precisely Box2DLights.

My problem is the following one : When I want to put a new "PointLight" it's always on the center of the screen. And if I change the coordinates, it doesn't work.

Inside my "show()" method :

```
    Box2D.init();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);

    rh = new RayHandler(world);
    rh.setAmbientLight(1.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.1f);
    pl = new PointLight(rh, 100, new Color(1,1,1,1),(float) 0.5,0,0);
```

Inside my "render()" method :

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f); 
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    world.step(delta, 8, 3);

    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    for (SolarSystem ss : solarSystemList)
    {
        if(ss.getColor() <= 15) colorSS = Color.YELLOW;
        else if(ss.getColor() > 15 && ss.getColor() < 31) colorSS = Color.ORANGE;
        else if(ss.getColor() > 30 && ss.getColor() < 46) colorSS = Color.RED;
        else if(ss.getColor() > 45) colorSS = Color.CYAN;

        renderer.setColor(colorSS);
        renderer.circle(ss.getMapX(), ss.getMapY(), ss.getSize() - 3);
    }
    renderer.end();

    rh.updateAndRender();
```

Result :

[image]
Now if I try to change coordinates :

```
pl = new PointLight(rh, 100, new Color(1,1,1,1),(float) 0.5, 50, 50);
```

[image]

... no light anymore

Do you know how it's possible to put the light where I want ?

EDIT : My screen size : width - 860px / height - 645px

Comment: are you using unit conversion for box2D? try maybe with setting position like ( 0.5f, 0.5f )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the (1,1) is the top right and the (0,0) is bottom left and the (0.5,0.5) is the middle of the screen, then i propose to do this :
insert the value that you want and divide it by the width and height of of your screen for example

```
 ( xPosition/Gdx.graphics.width, yPosition/Gdx.graphics.height )
```

**Update :**

sorry i didn't see that (0,0) was the center so i propse to you to use this instead :

```
width  = Gdx.graphics.width;
height = Gdx.graphics.height;
((xPosition - width/2)/ width/2 , (yPosition - height/2)/ height/2)
```

**Update 2 :**
i think you are doing little arithmetic mistake assume that your

width = 860 and your height = 645 as you said

this is the equation :

x= ((xPosition - width/2)/ width/2)

y= (yPosition - height/2)/ height/2)

x = (50 - 860/2) / (860/2)

y = (50 - 645/2) / (645/2)

x = (50 - 430) / (430)

y = (50 - 322.5) / (322.5)

x = (50 - 430) / (430) = (-380) / (430)

y = (50 - 322.5) / (322.5) = (-272.5) / (322.5)

**x = -0.88**

**y = -0.84**

which is closer to (-1,-1) aka : the left bottom corner

hope it was helpful :)

Comment: In fact, your idea is good but it's not exactly like that because (0,0) is the center of the screen. So it's more complicated

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work so well. For example if I try to display these coordinates -> (50 - width/2)/width/2   and  (50 - height/2)/height/2)  I will obtain x = -0,22... and y = -0,21...                                     This is closer to the center than the left bottom corner and we need to have to the opposite. My screen -> 860px, 645px.                                               I hope I'am clear enough

Comment: hi Simulacre, take a look at Update 2, x = -0.88, y = -0.84 and not (-0.22,-0.21)

Comment: Hi Minos. Fabulous, it's working ! And indeed, I did a little mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you take a distance of `0.5` and your light shines above half of the screen I just assume that a position of `50, 50` will not fit into this screen. Just try to change your position to a smaller value. [Maybe your coordinates do not represent pixels but other units as it is recommended for box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089303/libgdx-box2d-pixel-to-meter-conversion).

Edit: As I don't know your entire libgdx app I just recommend to have a deeper look into `Camera`, `ViewPort` and such. For example the box2dlights `RayHandler` can get your camera via `setCombinedMatrix`. You may also want to synchronize lights with bodies and the box2d world with your sprites.

Comment: That's it.  If I choose (0, 0), it's on the center.  If I choose (1,1), it's in the right corner, on the top. And if I choose (-1, -1), it's below, in the left corner. If I want to put light on my solar systems, how it's possible to convert that ? Thx