# Box2d body not responding to inputs

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, gravity

I'm using libgdx and box2d and I want to make my player's body jump.  Nothing happens when I try to use some methods even if it's just for moving.

```
//gravity Vector2
Vector2 Gravity = new Vector2(0,-9.8);
//Box2d World
World world = New World(gravity);

//then I created my player body
public void createPlayer(){
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.fixedRotation = true;
    def.position.set(80, 200);
    player = world.createBody(def);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(20, 20);
    player.createFixture(shape, 1f);
    shape.dispose();
}

//this is the jump method
public void jump(){
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched() == true) {
        player.applyForceToCenter(0, 900, false);
        System.out.println("touched");//to make sure the touch is working`
    }
}
```

Nothing happens and the player's body just falls until it collides to a static body, every time I touch the screen it only prints out the "touched" string.

**UPDATE**

Not sure if this is the reason why it's not working, I have two classes one for rendering and one for updating. On the update class I set the world.step() and not directly to the class where my body is.

```
//class for updating

public void update(float deltaTime){
    physics.world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
    physics.jump(); //calling jump method from Physics class
}
```

Same thing for the rendering class, `Box2dDebugRenderer` is seperated where my bodies are

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem, my Physics class which is connected to the Update and Render class had a reference to the create method of the main class, I don't understand because that's what I did for the constructor of my other classes.

```
public void create(){
    physics = new Physics(); //object for the Physics constructor.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are working with the box2d scale which is in meter 
So your Box your creating is (20 meter x 20 meter) so a force of "300" is not enough to move it up
to work with box2d you need to convert your values

divide all your box2d value by "WOLRD_TO_BOX" value scale

this post maybe helpful

[Libgdx Box2D pixel to meter conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089303/libgdx-box2d-pixel-to-meter-conversion)

Good luck

**Update :**

try change the

```
Gdx.input.justTouched()
```

to

```
Gdx.input.isTouched()
```

because the JustTouched() method is called just once (not in a continue way)

Comment: I tried to set the body to 5x5 meter then the force to 900 but the same thing happens, also can you set the weight of a body?

Comment: you can put the density of body in fixtureDef: try something like : fixtureDef.density = 0.1f

Comment: see the update of my answer you are calling Gdx.input.justTouched()  which is called just one time

Answer (score 1):

Your `jump()` , `World.step(...)`, `debugRender.render(...)` function should go on the `render()` method and the `createPlayer()` on should be on the `create()` method

```
 @Override
 public void create() {
        createPlayer()

 }

 @Override
 public void render() {
    //OpenGL settings
     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     world.step(TIME_STEP, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
     jump();
     debugRendrer.render(world, camera.combined);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did, on my render class I have my own render method which goes to the render method on the main class, the same for my update method.

Comment: Also this is the value for my step, physicsClass.world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the value that you are using, just make sure that the methods are in there right places

Comment: They are in the right places, I would have known if it's not cause every time i click the screen I printout a string

Comment: one last thing to try :  put the wake value to true player.applyForceToCenter(0, 300, true); and also reduce your density  player.createFixture(shape, 0.1f); hope its work cause it all that all i got (:/