# How meters to pixel and scaling works in Box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, pixel, meter

This is my first time using Box2d with Libgdx and I'm confused because now I'm dealing with meters and not pixels, for example if I wan't to set the size of my shape to 80x80 pixels, how do I do that in meters? Obviously I would have to zoom the camera which I have no idea how to do it. I wan't to know how can you set the amount of pixels needed to have one meter.

Comment: Have a look at this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089303/libgdx-box2d-pixel-to-meter-conversion?rq=1

Comment: Forget pixels even exist. Do everything in virtual world units (meters are the most popular). How fast is 10000 pixels per second? Or say how big is 100 px x 50 px car? Nobody can tell. But everybody would agree that 120 meters per second is fast and 1.2 m x 0.6 m car is small.